# How Improve pixel/resolution line using Gimp?

Tags: 14.04, resolution, gimp

How can I improve pixel/resolution line using Gimp in this file below?

[image: here]

It is very small and I want to increase it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can't magically add more information to an image than there is. The source image is too tiny to allow much further scaling without making the inherent artifacts too obvious:

[image]
<sup>Source image linearly scaled to 500%</sup>

However there is a somewhat better scale filter in the G'Mic plugin (install [gimp-gmic](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/gimp-gmic) [image: Install gimp-gmic]) then *G'Mic > Repair > Upscale (diffusion)*:

[image]
<sup>G'Mic upscale (diffusion) 500%</sup>

But still there are many unwanted artifacts and heavy aliasing which we will be unable to remove.

---

Much better results for such easy icons can be achieved by tracing the image automatically or even better manually to a vector graphic using [Inkscape](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/inkscape) [image: Install inkscape], which can then be scaled without loss:

[image]
<sup>500% scale for a) source image b) bitmap automatically traced c) manually traced/reconstructed image</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Now you can use neural networks for this kind of task. Look at [waifu2x](https://github.com/nagadomi/waifu2x) 
That is exactly what you are looking for. 
[Comparison with GIMP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nToYy.png)

Answer (score 1):

Open the file in GIMP. In the menu bar at the top, select Image > Scale Image. I suggest you leave the aspect ratio locked. Change the pixel dimension for, for instance, the height to whatever you desire. Save and close GIMP.

Caution: the original image is just 165x180 pixels. Scaling up will show somewhat poor quality as you cannot recover the detail that was lost when the image was previously scaled down. You might experiment with trying to improve the appearance with Filters > Enhance > Unsharp Mask and also Colors > Brightness, Contrast and then Contrast.